# Filtering 'shared mailbox users' with Graph API on Office 365 tenants

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am listing the users in the Office 365 tenant using Graph API version 1.6 following [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations).

I would like to filter the Office 365 shared mailboxes that are referenced as users and then returned when requesting `/users/`. (ex. `contact@contoso.com`, `support@contoso.com`).

From what I can see there is no way to distinguish a user representing a shared mailbox and a 'regular' user. Is someone has a mechanism to filter such mailboxes? Not that in my case the JSON member `userType` is always `null`.